# iOS 6 UITextView could not delete equal constraint

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm having trouble with auto layout in my `UITextView`. The `Textview` is over a `UiView`. The width of my `view` in storyboard is equal, but the height has to resize to support the iPhone 5.

The problem is that there is always a constraint with an equal height which I cannot delete. If i change this to "Greater or lower than" and change the value, I always have a equal height and the variable height in my constraints of the `textview`. I can only delete my greater than constraint from the `textview`.

If i change the constraint to "Promote to user constraint" I can delete it, but immediately there is a new constraint which pins the height.

Changing the priority to 1 doesn't solve the problem.

So the height of the view doesn't resize automatically.

On an other view the resize of my tableview works like it should, only the textview makes here problems.

How can I delete the equal constraint so that only the constraint greater than is active?

Edit:
Here is the source code from the view including the constraints.

```
                        <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="PNS-qQ-Qo3">
                            <subviews>
                                <textView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="RdG-Gf-pbO">
                                    <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                                    <constraints>
                                        <constraint firstAttribute="height" priority="1" constant="158" type="user" id="h7G-zb-nwt"/>
                                        <constraint firstAttribute="height" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" constant="158" type="user" id="oh5-nf-nRk"/>
                                    </constraints>
                                    <string key="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda.</string>
                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                                    <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits" autocapitalizationType="sentences"/>
                                </textView>
                            </subviews>
                            <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                            <constraints>
                                <constraint firstItem="RdG-Gf-pbO" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="PNS-qQ-Qo3" secondAttribute="leading" type="default" id="6vI-dT-4NX"/>
                                <constraint firstItem="RdG-Gf-pbO" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="PNS-qQ-Qo3" secondAttribute="trailing" type="default" id="Jkf-Hd-9rp"/>
                                <constraint firstItem="RdG-Gf-pbO" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="PNS-qQ-Qo3" secondAttribute="top" constant="20" symbolic="YES" type="default" id="v4W-JC-W0R"/>
                            </constraints>
                        </view>
```

Edit 2:
Here is the source code with the changes in the superview:

```
                        <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="PNS-qQ-Qo3">
                            <subviews>
                                <textView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="RdG-Gf-pbO">
                                    <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                                    <constraints>
                                        <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="158" id="0fk-CS-M1r"/>
                                        <constraint firstAttribute="height" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" constant="158" type="user" id="Mjt-GD-N8k"/>
                                    </constraints>
                                    <string key="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda.</string>
                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                                    <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits" autocapitalizationType="sentences"/>
                                </textView>
                            </subviews>
                            <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                            <constraints>
                                <constraint firstItem="RdG-Gf-pbO" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="PNS-qQ-Qo3" secondAttribute="trailing" type="user" id="7gP-1C-I3d"/>
                                <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" relation="lessThanOrEqual" secondItem="RdG-Gf-pbO" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="85" type="user" id="MlS-gF-VZh"/>
                                <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="300" type="user" id="NTZ-bO-H1C"/>
                                <constraint firstItem="RdG-Gf-pbO" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="PNS-qQ-Qo3" secondAttribute="leading" type="user" id="PsM-KW-5oX"/>
                                <constraint firstItem="RdG-Gf-pbO" firstAttribute="top" relation="lessThanOrEqual" secondItem="PNS-qQ-Qo3" secondAttribute="top" constant="58" type="user" id="Ugg-3p-tLX"/>
                                <constraint firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="RdG-Gf-pbO" secondAttribute="centerX" type="user" id="Z5B-5s-oK9"/>
                                <constraint firstAttribute="height" relation="lessThanOrEqual" constant="273" type="user" id="cCP-z5-3jO"/>
                                <constraint firstItem="RdG-Gf-pbO" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="PNS-qQ-Qo3" secondAttribute="top" constant="21" type="user" id="xnR-aM-hzt"/>
                            </constraints>
                        </view>
```

Comment: CAN U POST CODE AS WELL.

Comment: I have done everything in the Interface-Builder. The view only have an outlet to set the text.
How can i get the code?

Answer (score 0):

The interface builder will automatically re-add constraints whenever there are insufficient existing constraints to position the view (or any other related view) in both dimensions.

Generally, an issue like this means either that you're overlooking some obvious dependency (which I do all the time), or that there's another view further down the auto-layout chain (for lack of a better term) which needs the constraint to exist.  It doesn't have to be the view you're looking at.

It's hard to be sure without seeing the actual layout, but it sounds to me like the view at the other end of the equal height constraint might not have its layout defined without the constraint.

Have a look at that view, and in particular, see if adding a constraint such as vertical distance to superview (thus fixing the height) removes the issue.

Comment: Because of my new member state i am not able to post some screenshots from the layout.
I can only add the source code with the changed values from the root-view.

Comment: I've added the sources under Edit 2, maybe this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the constraint as an outlet into ".h" file and use the below code:

```
[self.yourview removeConstraint:self.yourconstraint];
```